# C# Object data stored internally vs in files

Tags: c#, performance, storage

I am working on a game with a lot of items. I was wondering if it's more efficient to store object data inside my program internally, or load a list of items from a file.

Example
[internal]:

```
Item sword = new Item();
sword.Damage = 40f;
sword.Value = 100;
Weapons.add(sword);
```

[external]
items.txt

```
name:sword
damage:40  
value:100

LoadItems("items.txt");
```

A was thinking storing object data in files could mean players could tamper or corrupt the files, and adding new objects would be easier in the IDE. Is one more efficient than the other?

Comment: [Horses](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)... As you've pointed out there are plenty of benefits and drawbacks of either approach - it is really up to you to decide which one is more suitable for particular project.

Comment: Side note: there is not much difference between code and data when it is stored on user's machine from security point of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A. Stored in Memory**

Pros:

1. Fast performance.
2. Less validation.

Cons:

1. If data is too large, application consume so much memory.
2. Data loss in app crash.

**B. Stored in File**

Pros:

1. Less worry about data size. If data grows, application hardly face memory issue.
2. If app crash you can get the data from file. (If file is not corrupt)

Cons:

1. Add validation.
2. Reading from file and parsing.
3. Add exception handling during process.

Here your main factor is data size. If its small save in memory. If its large save it in file.

Answer (score 0):

Usually data should be stored outside the program (not *hardcoded*) apart from the issues @Jigneshk said (which are all good guides), hardcoded data will make harder to develop game content (for example, you will have to code every sword in game) while an outside file could easily grow (even with the same program, as an update or mod) in content, so I would recommend putting all game-content (stats etc.) in a separate file (check an structured file like XML or JSON, even a sqlite database could work)

But of course have in mind that storage is slower (so you have to load before using it), and you shouldn't read **all** data, but load chunks of what you need (one level for example)